# Drag and Rotate MC in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, rotation, drag

I am trying to take a movieclip inside of an AS3 file and make it rotate smoothly when someone clicks and drags it. I know my code is close but right now instead of dragging, it moves a fixed distance on click. You can see the sample here: http://server.iconixinc.com/drag/

and here is my code

```
const TO_DEGREE:Number = 180/Math.PI;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startRotate, true);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopRotate, true);
var maxRotSpeed:Number = .1;
var rotScale:Number = 0.2;

function startRotate(e:MouseEvent):void
{



var dx:int = stage.mouseX - myMc.x;
    var dy:int = stage.mouseY - myMc.y;
    var rot:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * TO_DEGREE;
    var drot = rot - myMc.rotation;

    if(drot < -180) drot += 360;
    if(drot > 180) drot -= 360;

    drot *= rotScale;
    myMc.rotation += drot;
}

function stopRotate(e:MouseEvent) {
myMc.stopDrag();
}
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually using the drag and drop features of AS3, so you don't need the call to `stopDrag`. You're actually very close, you just want to move your code into a move listener:

```
const TO_DEGREE:Number = 180/Math.PI;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startRotate, true);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopRotate, true);
var maxRotSpeed:Number = .1;
var rotScale:Number = 0.2;

function startRotate(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // you want the calculation to occur whenever the mouse moves, 
    // not just when the mouse button is clicked
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
}

function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var dx:int = stage.mouseX - myMc.x;
    var dy:int = stage.mouseY - myMc.y;
    var rot:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * TO_DEGREE;
    var drot = rot - myMc.rotation;

    if(drot < -180) drot += 360;
    if(drot > 180) drot -= 360;

    drot *= rotScale;
    myMc.rotation += drot;

}

function stopRotate(e:MouseEvent) {
    // instead of calling stopDrag, you simply remove the move listener
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
}
```